# Google Analytic Disparity

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

From March 28th there is a disparity in Google Analytics when compared to the same day to next day.

For example 16th April night it shows 26,649 but if see it next day its decreased by 2k.

I have few AMP pages too on my site, I hope that's not making this disparity.

[image]  (16th night)

[image]  (later day)

[image]  (Comparison)

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you're not comparing the same requests: for the 16th you're making a comparison with the 9th ([which might trigger sampling and explain why numbers differ](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en)) whereas for the later request you're only querying for the 16th.

Make the same April 16 vs 9 comparison again and see at the top of your report if the results are being sampled.

Comment: Nope, We are observing for many days I don't have a screenshot. Above I have posted comparison report taken today

Comment: Any issues in the notifications box in the top right corner? If it happens again in the future, you should try to segment the reports (on the day and later) per browser, channel, device category, country etc... and see if you are losing your users for particular segments or is it spread across the board, might give you a clue. Apart from this, and obviously assuming you're looking at the same view :) I really don't see where problem could be coming from.

Comment: Yes am looking at the same view, Even asked in so many forums not getting any help. I will try separating and its been happening from many days.

Comment: Yes do the segmentation and let me know if you find any patterns. To make your life easier: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on